# MySQl Error : #1140 - Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query to calculate sum of each column from a table selecting sum and column values.

```
    $query = "select sum(salleryallowance), 
sum(entertainmentexp),
sum(depreciation), 
sum(electricity), 
sum(securitygard),
sum(machinaryrepaire), 
sum(totalrepairing),
sum(othermaintanaice),
sum(postal_charge),
sum(officeexp), 
sum(stationary),
sum(rent_lease_thresher), 
sum(rent_tractor), 
sum(traivlingallowance),
sum(transportaion_cost), 
sum(bank_commition), 
sum(total_exp),
sum(interest_earned), 
bit_farm.name as fname, 
bit_regional.name as rname 
from bit_income_expenditure 
inner join bit_farm on bit_income_expenditure.farm_id = bit_farm.id 
inner join bit_regional on bit_income_expenditure.region_id = bit_regional.id
";
$fetch = mysql_query($query);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch);

// and print my output

echo $row[0]; //and so on....
```

When I execute this code, it shows following error:

Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

How can I solve this error?

Comment: This is an error with your query. Please post the full query, if you want help with it.

Comment: this is my actual query.... @AdrianBR

Comment: your query is non standard sql and it is an illegal grouping by sql standards, due to having non aggregated columns mixed with aggregated with no group by. You either need to max() them to select a specific value, or group by them. The columns I am refering to are bit_farm.name as fname, 
bit_regional.name as rname

Comment: thank you  it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use any function like sum(),avg(), count()...then by default it will sum/count/avg of all data but if you use any other column based on which you want to categorized your sum/count/avg then you must mention group by after where clause, so your query should be-

```
select sum(salleryallowance), 
sum(entertainmentexp),
sum(depreciation), 
sum(electricity), 
sum(securitygard),
sum(machinaryrepaire), 
sum(totalrepairing),
sum(othermaintanaice),
sum(postal_charge),
sum(officeexp), 
sum(stationary),
sum(rent_lease_thresher), 
sum(rent_tractor), 
sum(traivlingallowance),
sum(transportaion_cost), 
sum(bank_commition), 
sum(total_exp),
sum(interest_earned), 
bit_farm.name as fname, 
bit_regional.name as rname 
from bit_income_expenditure 
inner join bit_farm on bit_income_expenditure.farm_id = bit_farm.id 
inner join bit_regional on bit_income_expenditure.region_id = bit_regional.id
group by bit_farm.name,bit_regional.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `select` clause includes:

```
 bit_farm.name as fname, bit_regional.name as rname
```

MySQL will accept this by default, but your system must have the default settings to be ANSI compliant.

It depends what you want.  If you want a different value for each "farm" and "region", then add:

```
 group by bit_farm.name, bit_regional.name
```

If you want an overall total, then remove these columns from the `select`.

Comment: yes its working after removing these two columns but i need these columns and after adding group by it is still showing this error:                  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by bit_farm.name as fname, bit_regional.name as rname from bit_income_expe' at line 1